# How do I switch between graphics cards without turning off the computer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I've got an NVIDIA graphics card that is currently active. I'd like to switch to using the graphics card on the motherboard *without turning off the computer*.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Edit: To make it clear, I can log off and on, but I cannot shut off or reboot the computer because other users are logged in remotely and running jobs.

Comment: Am I the only one that initially thought the question was about physically swapping 2 video boards out while powered on?... Man, that would be an awesome question.

Comment: More information would be nice. I'm assuming this is a desktop? Do you actually want to power down the other graphics card when you switch over to the integrated graphics?

Comment: Yes, it is a desktop. No, I'd like to leave it running.

Comment: @user545424 maybe you make a bit clearer what your understanding of "turning off" implies: Would a reboot be acceptable (as it is, technically speaking, no "power-off")? Would a logout/re-login be? Or don't you want to close any running application (speaking of a "hot-swap")?

Comment: @BrianAdkins Yeah, my first thought was: "Next question: How to replace the CPU without stopping any app from running" *lol* But reading the entire question, the meaning is quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, it would be done via restarting Xorg with a config file that uses the `intel` driver (or other as appropriate for the on-board video) instead of the `nouveau`/`nvidia` driver.

Answer (score 0):

Three different ways to accomplish this

1) If possible try to disable it in the bios of your computer before it actually loads Ubuntu

2) blacklist it in the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf then log out of Ubuntu and log back in.

3) just unplug the power to the graphics card and see if switches over to the onboard one

Comment: I'm not really sure how to accomplish 1). 3) I don't want to stop the graphics card, I just want my display to run on the integrated graphics.

Comment: who makes your motherboard and what is the model?

Comment: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16813131733

Comment: 1) would require at least a reboot. Though technicall this is no "turning off the computer", I guess the intention of the question excludes this. Similarly for 2) I guess, as the intention as I understood is temporarily re-route the output without stopping the running applications (@user545424 maybe you should make that a bit clearer in your question to avoid guesswork).